# SSL decryption/visibility on the host

Tags: encryption, network, vpn

Can host app see traffic before network encryption? E.g. can a host-based VPN app see cleartext traffic (http to https) to make any traffic routing decisions? Considering the TCP/IP model, all operate at the Application layer.

Comment: What traffic. It's own? Other traffic?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Yes, VPNs can make routing decisions, but they do not need the HTTP information to do that (routing is in IP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is handled inside the applications (like browsers) themselves by using libraries like SChannel, Secure Transport, OpenSSL, NSS etc. This means only encrypted traffic enters or leaves the applications. Anybody wanting to get access to the plain traffic without being an active man in the middle would need to inject itself into the  process of the running original application or would need to modify the application binary or similar.

I'm not aware of any VPN which would do this and it is also not needed for any routing decisions. Routing is done at the level of the IP addresses (Layer 3) and not at the application level.